# Google Analytics Bounce Rates - which page is bouncing the most?

Tags: google-analytics, bounce-rate, bounce

I want to know which of my pages have the highest bounce rates so I can fix them. Ideally, I would also know if they are bouncing on desktop or in mobile. Is this something I can find out in Google Analytics?

Comment: You should be able to sort the columns by clicking on the column header. You can sort them ascending or descending. Of course, for me it seems anyway, clicking the column to sort always seems to be the wrong way. Of course, it only takes another click to sort the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can see bounce rate for each page and if it's mobile or not!

1) In your GA you need to go to Behaviour > Site content > All Pages

2) Then you have an option Secondary Dimension (below the graph) [image]

3) When you start typing "mobile" you can see that there are different options. The Mobile (Including Tablet) is what you're looking for.